# Angular 5 Custom-Error-Handler: Display Error-message

Tags: javascript, html, angular, error-handling, angular5

I'm trying to create an error-handler for Angular 5. If an error is fired through my CustomErrorHandler, the frontend should be updated.
The problem is that nothing changes, after the variable is updated.

error-handler.service.ts

```js
import {ErrorHandler, Injectable} from '@angular/core';
import {Subject} from "rxjs/Subject";

@Injectable()
export class CustomErrorHandler implements ErrorHandler {
    message: String = "";
    isVisible: boolean = false;

    visibilityChange: Subject<boolean> = new Subject<boolean>();

    constructor() {
        this.visibilityChange.subscribe((value) => {
            this.isVisible = value
        });
    }

    handleError(error) {
        console.error(error);
        this.message = "ERROR: " + error.toString();
        this.visibilityChange.next(true);
    }
}
```

error-message.component.ts

```js
import {Component} from '@angular/core';
import {CustomErrorHandler} from "../../../services/error-handler.service";

@Component({
    selector: 'app-error-message',
    templateUrl: './error-message.html',
})

export class ErrorMessageComponent {
    public message: String = "";
    public isVisible: boolean = false;

    constructor(private customErrorHandler: CustomErrorHandler) {
        this.isVisible = customErrorHandler.isVisible;
    }
}
```

error-handler.html

```html
<div class="alert alert-danger" id="app-error" *ngIf="isVisible">
    {{message}}
</div>
```

app.html

```html
<app-nav></app-nav>
<div class="container">
    <div class="jumbotron">
        <app-error-message></app-error-message>
        <app-info-message></app-info-message>
        <router-outlet></router-outlet>
    </div>
</div>
<app-footer></app-footer>
```

app.module.ts

```js
@NgModule({
    declarations: [
        AppComponent,
        ErrorMessageComponent,
        .....
    ],
    imports: [
        BrowserModule,
        FormsModule,
        HttpClientModule,
        AngularFontAwesomeModule,
        routing
    ],
    providers: [
        UserService,
        {
            provide: ErrorHandler,
            useClass: CustomErrorHandler
        },
        CustomErrorHandler
    ],
    bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule {
}
```

Has somebody an idea what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Custom `ErrorHandler` implementation is supposed to be provided in module, which will be used instead of the default one. You can have a service to manage the messages and a component that injects the service to show the messages. Your custom error handler can update the service when errors arise. Can you explain how you are expecting your setup to work?

Comment: Also, are you looking for handling http errors or all sort of errors being thrown?

Comment: The idea of this implementation would be, to display a short descripton of errors on the frontend and log everything in detail in a logfile.
It should display especially HTTP Errors, but should be also able to display all sorts of errors.

You are right, CustomErrorHandler should be a service.

Comment: Create an `ErrorLogger` service and inject it to `CustomErrorHandler`. `CustomErrorHandler` will then intercept the error and send it to `ErrorLogger`, your `log` logic can be done in the `ErrorLogger` service. Also throw the error from custom error handler after interception.

Comment: For `http` related errors, angular supports HttpInterceptor, which can be used for logging http calls in a similar fashion.

Comment: I edited the post. CustomErrorHandler is now a Service, but it didn't fix my problem.
I want to use just one Errorhandler for everything, if this is possible (or a good idea)

Comment: Try to run inside Ngzone.run function. You can get Ngzone by constructor dependency

Comment: Did you provide this custom error handler as the default error handler in your module?

Comment: @sabithpocker: Yes. I added aüü.moudle.ts to the question

Comment: @AnkitRana: Can you explain this a little bit more or can you show me a tutorial?

Comment: @PeterHoritzer, check out this gist for reference : https://gist.github.com/code-atom/88ef20d1a4c79120a4f3333b7fb7cb9b

Answer (score 0):

for rxjs subscribe, you may have to use changedetection.

```
    constructor(private changeDetection: ChangeDetectorRef) {
    this.visibilityChange.subscribe((value) => {
        this.isVisible = value; this.changeDetection.detectChanges();
    });
}
```

Comment: Why is that needed? Can you elaborate in your answer